# How to debug in spyder line by line without enterting external libraries

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

When i try to debug in spyder line by line, it keeps entering external libraries like "iostream" for example or whatever libraries the code need it.
However, when I tried visual studio code, it worked correctly and only went through my source code lines.
Is it possible to make spyder works in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To avoid entering in external Python libraries while debugging, you need to go the menu

```
Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Debugger
```

and enable the option called `Ignore Python libraries while debugging`.

Answer (score 3):

Take care to distinguish between `n` next source line
versus `s` step *into* a function.

As a last resort you can always set a `b` breakpoint
a few lines down in your function,
and then `c` continue silently executing all the code
in between, including library calls.